# Why purescript can infer the Row.Cons contraint?

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I have a newtype which takes a parameterized type,

```hs
newtype MockState m = MockState { apiState :: {api1 :: m Int, api2:: m String} }
derive instance newtypeMockState :: Newtype (MockState m) _
```

I have a function that creates a ref out of some field,

```hs
createRef :: forall s a b r r' rem 
        .  IsSymbol s
        => Newtype (MockState Identity) {apiState :: Record r}
        => Row.Cons s (Identity a) r' r 
        => Proxy s 
        -> MockState Identity
        -> Effect (Ref.Ref a)
createRef pxy (MockState mockState)= do 
      let (Identity val) = Record.get pxy mockState.apiState
      Ref.new val
```

Why the compiler can't resolve the constraint?

```hs
  No type class instance was found for

    Prim.Row.Cons s4
                  (Identity a5)
                  t2
                  ( cla :: Identity String
                  , login :: Identity Int
                  )
```

When I pass `Record r` directly insted of my newtype, it compiles without any issue... and the below also works..

```hs
createRef :: forall s a b mock r' r rem 
        .  IsSymbol s
        => Newtype mock {apiState :: Record r}
        => Row.Cons s (Identity a) r' r 
        => Proxy s 
        -> mock
        -> Effect (Ref.Ref a)
createRef pxy r = do 
      let (Identity val) = Record.get pxy (unwrap r).apiState
      Ref.new val
```

but how? Literally the first one and last are same right? Why the compiler can't infer `r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the compiler can't see a connection between your `Newtype` constraint and the pattern `(MockState mockState)`. These are technically unrelated. The `Newtype` class is not magic enough for this.

So `mockState` is inferred to be of type `{ apiState :: Record r1 }`, where `r1` is distinct from `r`, and therefore constraint `Cons s (Identity a) r' r` does not apply to `r1`.

In order to get the right type inference, you have to unwrap your newtype by utilizing the `Newtype` constraint itself. Then the unwrapped value will have type `{ apiState :: Record r }`, and the `Cons` constraint will apply.

You can do this by using [the `unwrap` function](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-newtype/5.0.0/docs/Data.Newtype#v:unwrap):

```hs
createRef pxy mockState= do
      let (Identity val) = Record.get pxy (unwrap mockState).apiState
      Ref.new val
```